# CustomView extending RelativeLayout is not shown correctly

Tags: java, android, view

I created a custom view which has an elevation and uses a white background drawable. When I call it from xml , it is shown correctly on the xml editor but when I run it on my Marshmallow device , there is no elevation and white background at all.

```
public class ElevatedRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
private Context context;
public int ELEVATION = 10;

public ElevatedRelativeLayout(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setAttributes();
}

public ElevatedRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    setAttributes();

}

public ElevatedRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
    setAttributes();

}

private void setAttributes (){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21)
        this.setElevation(ELEVATION);
    this.setBackgroundDrawable(new CornerShapedDrawable(context, Color.WHITE , GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE, 30));
}}
```

CornerShapedDrawable :

```
public class CornerShapedDrawable extends Drawable {

int type = 0 ;
float corners = 0 ;
int backgroundColor;
public CornerShapedDrawable (Context context , int backgroundColor ,int type , float corners){
    this.type = type;
    this.corners = corners;
    this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] f = new float[]{corners,corners,corners,corners,0,0,0,0};
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.setCornerRadii(f);
    shape.setShape(type);
    shape.setColor(backgroundColor);
    shape.setStroke(3 , Color.WHITE);
}}
```

What's the problem in here? I tried overriding the onDraw method but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think your custom RelativeLayout can't draw the shadow of your view because of its parent bounds.

Maybe try to put this in the parent layout :

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```